# joining two queries using join in mysql

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have following two queries

1)

```
SELECT  `domains`.`name` ,  `pageviews`.`domain_id` , COUNT(  `pageviews`.`domain_id` ) 
FROM  `pageviews` 
LEFT JOIN  `domains` ON (  `domains`.`id` =  `pageviews`.`domain_id` 
AND  `domains`.`user_id` =  '129' ) 
WHERE  `pageviews`.`user_id` =  '129'
GROUP BY  `pageviews`.`domain_id` 
ORDER BY COUNT(  `pageviews`.`domain_id` ) DESC
```

2)

```
SELECT  `domains`.`name` ,  `visitors`.`ip` ,  `visitors`.`domain_id` , COUNT(  `visitors`.`domain_id` ) 
FROM  `visitors` 
LEFT JOIN  `domains` ON (  `domains`.`id` =  `visitors`.`domain_id` 
AND  `domains`.`user_id` =  '129' ) 
WHERE  `visitors`.`user_id` =  '129'
GROUP BY  `visitors`.`domain_id` 
ORDER BY COUNT(  `visitors`.`domain_id` ) DESC
```

I want to combine these queries.
this is required for cakephp pagination because i want to show data in table and want to sort acc. to visitors and pageviews if i want.
associations are 1)  domains has many visitors   2) domains has many pageviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    pv.name,pv.domain_id,pv.counter as page_visits, v.ip, v.counter as visits
FROM (
    SELECT  `domains`.`name` ,  `pageviews`.`domain_id` , COUNT(  `pageviews`.`domain_id` ) as counter
    FROM  `pageviews` 
    LEFT JOIN  `domains` ON (  `domains`.`id` =  `pageviews`.`domain_id` 
    AND  `domains`.`user_id` =  '129' ) 
    WHERE  `pageviews`.`user_id` =  '129'
    GROUP BY  `pageviews`.`domain_id` 
    ORDER BY COUNT(  `pageviews`.`domain_id` ) DESC 
) as pv
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  `domains`.`name` ,  `visitors`.`ip` ,  `visitors`.`domain_id` , COUNT(  `visitors`.`domain_id` ) as counter
    FROM  `visitors` 
    LEFT JOIN  `domains` ON (  `domains`.`id` =  `visitors`.`domain_id` 
    AND  `domains`.`user_id` =  '129' ) 
    WHERE  `visitors`.`user_id` =  '129'
    GROUP BY  `visitors`.`domain_id` 
    ORDER BY COUNT(  `visitors`.`domain_id` ) DESC
) as v
    ON pv.domain_id = v.domain_id
```

Comment: how can i use your query in cakephp paginate ?I am new to cakephp and don't to to much about this..thanks

Comment: @gurpreetsingh sorry i'm not very familiar with cake php framework so i'm afraid i can't help you there